# How to pass parameter on jpa query?

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa-2.0

I have two entities Like **SmsOut** and **SmsIn**. The relation between two entities contains **OneToMany** where **smsIn.id** is **primary key** and **smsOut.sms_in_id** is **foreign key**.

Now I want to pass parameter like **smsIn.mobileNumber**, **smsIn.smsText** and so on, on the query

```
SELECT so FROM SmsOut so order by id desc
```

**Following is my database diagram:**

[image]

**Edited**

Following is my code :

```
String sql = "SELECT so FROM SmsOut so WHERE so.smsInId.mobileNumber =:mobileNumber AND so.smsInId.smsText =:smsText AND so.smsInId.shortCode =:shortCode between so.smsOutDate =:startDate and so.smsOutDate =:endDate order by id desc";
    Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
    query.setParameter("smsText", smsText);
    query.setParameter("shortCode", shortCode);
    query.setParameter("smsOutDate", startDate);
    query.setParameter("smsOutDate", endDate);
    smsOutList = query.getResultList();
```

and exception is :

```
SEVERE: line 1:188: expecting "and", found '='
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "and", found '=' near line 1, column 188 [SELECT so FROM     com.f1soft.SMSC.entities.SmsOut so WHERE so.smsInId.mobileNumber =:mobileNumber AND so.smsInId.smsText =:smsText AND so.smsInId.shortCode =:shortCode between so.smsOutDate =:startDate and so.smsOutDate =:endDate order by id desc]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:624)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
```

Please Help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't explained the JPA relationship between `SmsIn` and `SmsOut`, so I'll assume `SmsOut` has a `getSmsIn()` with a relation on the `id` field.

When you have an `EntityManager em`, you can call `em.createQuery`, which is like SQL `prepare`, and then `setParameter`:

```
TypedQuery<SmsOut> q = em.createQuery("SELECT so FROM SmsOut so WHERE so.smsIn.mobileNumber = :number ORDER BY id DESC");
q.setParameter("number", "12345678");
List<SmsOut> results = q.getResultList();
```

See [the Javadoc for `Query`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) for the different ways you can specify the parameters.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Where I am providing source code and log

Comment: You're using `=:` like it's a single token. While the whitespace isn't required, the syntax is `=` `:variableName`. In your `between` clause, you have extra `=` when you should say `so.smsInId.shortCode BETWEEN so.smsOutDate :startDate AND so.smsOutDate :endDate`, although even that doesn't really make sense--the shortcode is supposed to fall in a date range? Did you mean to have another clause with `smsInDate`?

Comment: I am still getting exception 'SEVERE: line 1:214: unexpected token: :' can you provide full query . Thanks

Comment: No, there is not another clause with smsInDate. I will use only this query which I am written on my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT so FROM SmsOut so WHERE smsIn.mobileNumber = ? AND smsIn.smsText =? order by id desc
```

Replace the ? sign with the apropiate values.

Answer (score 0):

between is the problem:

```
between so.smsOutDate =:startDate and so.smsOutDate =:endDate
```

try

```
so.smsOutDate between  =:startDate and =:endDate
```