# JPA equivalent of this mySql query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I want to write a `JPA` equivalent of this MySQL query.

```
SELECT status, is_deleted  FROM indent 
WHERE status = "in progress" AND is_deleted = false;
```

In the above query `status` and `is_deleted` are the column names of table and the value (here, for `status` and `is_deleted`, the values are `in progress` & `false` respectively) are variables.

```
public interface IndentRepository extends JpaRepository<Indent, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT i.status FROM indent i where i.status = 'status AND is_deleted = 'condition")
    List<Indent> getByStatus(String status, boolean condition);

}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what is the occuring error  / problem?

Comment: I'm getting the result for
 **SELECT status, is_deleted FROM indent WHERE status = "in progress"**
and the later part of AND does not work

Comment: In your question, you said you need JPA equivalent of this query. So where is your JPA code that you are stuck into? Please post your attempts.

Comment: @ManojShukla I've edited posted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT i.status FROM indent i where i.status = :status AND i.is_deleted = :condition")
List<Indent> getByStatusAndIsDeleted(@Param ("status") String status,@Param ("condition") boolean condition);
```

The problem is using ' (single quote) for referring a parameter, it considers everything after it as parameter
So, I used org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param for denoting parameter and used : (colon) for referencing the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your query, at first look, it seems **INCORRECT** as the `i.status` is being assigned a string value, which is exactly `status AND is_deleted =` and the `condition` word is erroneous for query, as they don't fit in rules of `String` in Java.

You can use `namedQueries` which is quite better and more understandable at early stage of development.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172400/6446770) is how you can use `namedQueries`.